# display all images in folder using jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2

I sit possible to render a template by providing a folder path and let jinja2 find all the images in that folder and include them as images? Something like

```
{% for image in find_all_files_in_path(path) %}
   <img src="{{ image }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. **Jinja2** only render the context you pass into the templates through variables. So you should send to the template a list with the image urls for jinja to be able to render your images. And then you can loop over this sequence;

```
{% for image_url in image_urls %}
   <img src="{{ image }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Commonly you use jinja with an web framework (like django, flask, etc) which gives you the possibility to access objects in the templates.